# Mongoose instance method to modify 'this' document throws TypeError: Cannot set property '...' of undefined

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I tried creating a mongoose [instance method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods) to create a password reset token that I can send to users in an email.

I was basing my function off the [`dudify` method](https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-mongoosejs-in-node-js-and-mongodb-applications#custom-method) from a scotch.io tutorial called [Easily Develop Node.js and MongoDB Apps with Mongoose](https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-mongoosejs-in-node-js-and-mongodb-applications).

---

models.js

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...
    auth: {
        password: String,
        passToken: String,
        tokenExpires: Date
    },
    ...
});

userSchema.methods.createToken = function(next){
    require('crypto').randomBytes(16, function(err,buf){
        if (err){ next(err); }
        else {
            this.auth.passToken = buf.toString('hex');
            this.auth.tokenExpires = Date.now() + 3600000;
            this.save();
        }
    });
};
```

error

```
/path/to/project/config/models.js:85
    this.auth.passToken = buf.toString('hex');
                        ^

TypeError: Cannot set property 'passToken' of undefined
    at InternalFieldObject.ondone (/path/to/project/config/models.js:85:25)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `this` no longer referred to the model instance: it referred to `crypto.randomBytes()`.

My solution was set `this` to a variable (`user`) outside the function:

```
userSchema.methods.createToken = function(next){
    var user = this;
    require('crypto').randomBytes(16, function(err,buf){
       if (err){ next(err); }
        else {
            user.auth.passToken = buf.toString('hex');
            user.auth.tokenExpires = Date.now() + 3600000;
            user.save();
        }
    });
};
```

In retrospect, that was pretty stupid of me, but it happens to the best of us.  Hopefully this will save someone else time.